# How To Send Transactions Fees to Treasury Instead of Burning Tokens?

Tags: transaction-fees, gas, treasury

I am new to `Substrate` development, and I have installed locally the substrate node template. It works well, but for my little project the native token is linked to physical assets and by default in the node template project, it seem that the transactions fees are actually burning tokens from the total supply?

I am looking for a way (easy if possible!)  to not burn the transaction fees tokens, but instead send it to treasury or perhaps one of the admin wallet? I tried to modify the lib.rs file in the runtime folder this way, it compiled, but it did not worked and tokens are still burned when transactions occurs. Thanks in advance for your advices!

````rust
pub struct CustomFeeHandler;

impl pallet_transaction_payment::OnChargeTransaction for CustomFeeHandler {
    fn withdraw_fee(
        who: &AccountId, 
        call: &Call, 
        info: &DispatchInfo, 
        fee: Balance, 
        tip: Balance
    ) -> Result<(), TransactionValidityError> {
        // Verify that the account has enough balance to pay the fee
        if pallet_balances::Pallet::<Runtime>::free_balance(who) < fee {
            return Err(TransactionValidityError::from(InvalidTransaction::Payment));
        }

        // Withdraw the fee from the account
        let imbalance = pallet_balances::Pallet::<Runtime>::withdraw(
            who, 
            fee, 
            WithdrawReasons::TRANSACTION_PAYMENT, 
            ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive
        )?;

        // Deposit the fee into the treasury
        Treasury::<Runtime>::on_unbalanced(imbalance);

        Ok(())
    }
    
}


impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type OnChargeTransaction = CustomFeeHandler;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ConstFeeMultiplier<FeeMultiplier>;
}```
````

Comment: please roll back your last edit and post it as an answer to your own question instead it will make it easier for someone in the future who encounters the same problem to find your solution

Comment: and post the update you had as an aswer.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the `DealWithFees` as shown here: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/e0d20124b071d907cd7ccc163cc1a412caf95626/runtime/common/src/lib.rs#L226-L237.

And include the `DealWithFees` in the configuration of `TransactionPayment`, like this: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/e0d20124b071d907cd7ccc163cc1a412caf95626/runtime/darwinia/src/pallets/transaction_payment.rs#L27-L28

Why does `pallet_treasury`'s`on_unbalanced` function operate in this manner?
Because it is set up to behave like this: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/ac3f14d23ba0f4d7e92d70c2fe6b202ccdcb3a62/substrate/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L1113-L1122.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I have tried it and had some errors while compiling, but those were related to my old version of the lib.rs file, I somehow have refresh issues that is strange. I did cargo clean command prior compiling, but still the same. I will investigate more deeply over the w-e and come back reporting here!

Comment: Ok so I can't make it work unfortunately. I tried different approaches including the above.  But so far, I can't even setup the pallet_treasury alone even with all the config traits and have it to compile successfully. I followed that tutorial, but the treasury is far from being simple as the nicks pallet! https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-a-pallet/ Are there other treasury examples, perhaps on git,  that follow the node template with the recent code (not 3 years old)? Many thanks in advance!